# Stack around the variable 'DM' was corrupted

Tags: c, char, corrupt

Keep getting the error `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'DM' was corrupted.`

The code is

```
    int Repeats;
    double x_max;
    char DM[] = ""; 

    printf("\nPlease enter the number of repeats: ");
    scanf("%d", &Repeats);
    printf("\nPlease enter the length: ");
    scanf("%lf", &x_max);
    printf("\nAccount for Dark Matter?(Y/N) ");
    scanf("%s", DM);

    char lower_DM = tolower(DM[0]);

    DM[0] = lower_DM;

    printf("DM: %c", DM[0]);
```

I just want it to accept a single character, Y/N, (lower it for comparison so user can type Y, y, N or n with no issues) but once the full code runs, at the end it just says the stack around 'DM' was corrupted and I'm not sure why, as there should still only be a single character in the single character array I've defined at the start?

Thanks

Comment: DM is too small, you need more memory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you declare `DM` as : `char DM[] = "";`. The size of array character is too small. For yes or no request, you should use `char DM` that is enough. When you declare DM as a charater, use `scanf` like:

```
scanf(" %c", &DM);
```

But if you want to work with string, you can declare DM as:

```
char DM[] = "Y";
```

OR

```
char DM[2];
```

Comment: If you use the second approach then you should also use `%1s` in the `scanf` so that you don't overrun the buffer if the user accidentally types more characters.

Comment: Yes. For string, we should use fgets instead